# Unable to build android with ionic due to JDK-9

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I have an `ionic 2.0.0-rc0` app and I want to build n android platform. When I run
`ionic run android` , it fails in between. StackTrace-

```
   > ionic-hello-world@ build /home/raj/ionic/github
    > ionic-app-scripts build
    [07:46:11]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.23
    [07:46:11]  build prod started ...
    [07:46:11]  clean started ...
    [07:46:11]  clean finished in 9 ms
    [07:46:11]  copy started ...
    [07:46:11]  ngc started ...
    [07:46:11]  lint started ...
    [07:46:11]  copy finished in 171 ms
    [07:46:12]  lint finished in 960 ms
    [07:46:26]  ngc finished in 15.36 s
    [07:46:26]  bundle prod started ...
    [07:46:34]  bundle prod finished in 8.27 s
    [07:46:34]  sass started ...
    [07:46:36]  sass finished in 1.67 s
    [07:46:36]  minify started ...
    [07:46:36]  cleancss started ...
    [07:46:36]  uglifyjs started ...
    [07:46:47]  uglifyjs finished in 10.80 s
    [07:46:47]  cleancss finished in 10.80 s
    [07:46:47]  minify finished in 10.80 s
    [07:46:47]  build prod finished in 36.12 s
    Running command: /home/raj/ionic/github/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/raj/ionic/github

    :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED


    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    Error: /home/raj/ionic/github/platforms/android/gradlew: Command      failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Could not create an instance of type com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.
```

I am using genymotion as emulator, even though I dont think that matters in this issue. Many solution to this problem is setting  `JAVA_HOME` path. But I have set it,
`echo $JAVA_HOME > /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64` . I suspect this is a problem with `gradle 2.1` and `java-9` from [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-2-12-fails-to-build-when-running-on-jdk-9/15335)  . I have been stuck on this for some time now, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Android SDK don't support Java 9. downgrade to 8 (yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stupid me thought it would be a great idea to try out `JDK-9` when the great 
**Oracle** warned me not to . Removed it and installed `JDK-8` , problem solved. Oracle did see my future.

Comment: That's actually not a solution as JDK 9 is now the default download option on Oracle Java Website.

Comment: Thats because its stable now. My problem was due to an unstable version

Comment: But this answer is no longer a solution to this problem. :)

Comment: @incorelabs I can only speak for myself, but I tried to do this today with JDK 9 and the latest cordova  and it didn't work. This solution worked for me

Comment: @BradPitcher I guess for the time being we'll just have to downgrade to JDK 8, which seems not the most feasible but the only go to solution for now coz the people are Apache Cordova are not ready to allow JDK9. :/

Comment: I still have this problem with the latest cordova installed just today, I will have to downgrade my JDK

Answer (score -2):

```
 cordova platform update android
 ionic build android
 ionic run android
```

Try running these commands. Hope This will help you :)

Comment: Its the latest android version. So update is not the issue.

Comment: yes. ``     > Could not create an instance of type com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.`` . This is the issue. I think openjdk is the poblem. I am reinstalling it.

Comment: Go ahead . And please let me know if you solve your issue :)

Comment: Yup. That solved it. Stupid me thought it would be a great idea to try out JDK-9